# How to run pip install -U <package> with conda environment..yml

Tags: pip, anaconda

I am trying to find a way to have `conda env update` run `pip install` with upgrade flag on.

I have environment.yml file that I want to use for package management. However, when I run `conda env update environment.yml`, I noticed that the packages that are installed by pip is not getting the latest version.

For example with the environment.yml below, when I run the `conda env update` command it would say:

`Requirement already satisfied: robotframework in /usr/local/anaconda3/envs/demo_utils/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r /Users/xyz/src/demo_utils/condaenv.z0hiwexk.requirements.txt (line 12)) (3.0.4)`

However, there is a robotframework is 3.1.1 and I could only install that with `pip install -U robotframework`. It seems like when we do `conda env update`, conda runs the pip command without the upgrade flag.

```
name: demo_utils
dependencies:
  - python>=3.6
  - numpy
  - matplotlib
  - requests
  - pip
  - pip:
    - jira
    - PyGithub
    - slackclient
    - slackweb
    - jenkinsapi
    - jenkins-python
    - robotframework-pabot
    - boto3
    - sauceclient
    - robotframework
```

Is there a way to have conda run update with pip upgrade flag on?

Answer (score 0):

I think `pip` would run automatically with `-U` if the specified channels work like that. A channel that does that is `conda-forge`, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71692666/upgrading-pip-to-latest-version-using-pip-in-conda-using-environment-yaml) answer.
It seems [this](https://github.com/conda/conda/pull/8542/commits/810dd45a0aba2ee96a3afe5830b83abe1a672ec2) (old) commit in `conda` is doing exactly what you are looking for and it has been merged to master. `conda env update` is using `-U` by default. So, I would suggest adding the channel in the `requirements.yml`.